# Draw a graph of an interval varying function

Tags: plotting

I have a function，I want to plot it

[image]

This piecewise function looks very complicated, because the boundary changes as c changes.
want to just Plot it, not Manipulate

To solve this problem, I first do it manually, one by one.Here c takes on three special values,like this

[image]

Then use the Show function to integrate them
[image]

This is very complicated and requires constant manual operation,Therefore, I improved my approach by discretizing C, defining functions of each interval separately, and finally integrating them with piecewise functions

```mathematica
(*=== 常数 ===*)
Clear["Global`*"]
rf = 0;
theta = 0.1;
p = 1;

(*=== 边界 ===*)
boundary1 = 0;
boundary2 = c;
boundary3 = 
  c*(2 - c (1 + rf)/(1 - theta)*p + (1 - theta)*p/(1 + rf) - c) + 
   1/2 ((1 - theta)*p/(1 + rf) - c)^2;
boundary4 = 2;

(*=== 分段函数定义 ===*)
funb1[b_] := 0;
funb2[b_] := -c - (2^(1/3)*(-6 b + 12 c - 
        3 c^2))/(3 *(54 c^2 + 
         Sqrt[2916 c^4 + 4 (-6 b + 12 c - 3 c^2)^3])^(1/
         3)) + (54 c^2 + 
       Sqrt[2916 c^4 + 4*(-6 b + 12 c - 3 c^2)^3])^(1/3)/(3*2^(1/3));
funb3[b_] := (1 - theta)*p/(1 + rf) - c;

fun = Table[(Through[{funb1, funb2, funb3}@{x}] // Flatten), {c, 0.3, 
    0.8, 0.01}];
boundary = 
  Table[{boundary1, boundary2, boundary3, boundary4}, {c, 0.3, 0.8, 
    0.01}];
```

I'm discretizing C, so I'm using these two lines of code

```mathematica
fun = Table[(Through[{funb1, funb2, funb3}@{x}] // Flatten), {c, 0.3, 
    0.8, 0.01}];
boundary = 
  Table[{boundary1, boundary2, boundary3, boundary4}, {c, 0.3, 0.8, 
    0.01}];
```

After I discretize C, then I want to define the piecewise function that I want once and for all, but I don't know how to do it, and defining the piecewise function manually would be very, very tedious.

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Are you aware of the command `Piecewise` see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)?

Comment: @user293787 I know that, but I don't know how to define it all at once, I have to do it manually, okay

Comment: Your question contains a lot of info, some of which may not be relevant to your actual problem, so let me take something simpler such as `f[c_,x_] := Piecewise[{{0,0<=x<=c},{x-c,c<=x<=2*c},{c,2*c<=x<=2}}]`. Suppose we then set `p[c_] := Plot[f[c,x],{x,0,2}]`. Then `p[0.2]` and `p[0.7]` will give you two plots. Does this help?

Comment: @user293787 yes,this is a good idea,use two vars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set all of the functions depend on `c`.

```
(*===常数===*)Clear["Global`*"]
rf = 0;
theta = 0.1;
p = 1;

(*===边界===*)
boundary1[c_] = 0;
boundary2[c_] = c;
boundary3[c_] = 
  c*(2 - c (1 + rf)/(1 - theta)*p + (1 - theta)*p/(1 + rf) - c) + 
   1/2 ((1 - theta)*p/(1 + rf) - c)^2;
boundary4[c_] = 2;

(*===分段函数定义===*)
funb1[c_][b_] = 0;
funb2[c_][
   b_] = -c - (2^(1/3)*(-6 b + 12 c - 
        3 c^2))/(3*(54 c^2 + 
         Sqrt[2916 c^4 + 4 (-6 b + 12 c - 3 c^2)^3])^(1/
         3)) + (54 c^2 + 
       Sqrt[2916 c^4 + 4*(-6 b + 12 c - 3 c^2)^3])^(1/3)/(3*2^(1/3));
funb3[c_][b_] = (1 - theta)*p/(1 + rf) - c;
f[c_][b_] = 
  Which[boundary1[c] <= b <= boundary2[c], funb1[c][b], 
   boundary2[c] < b < boundary3[c], funb2[c][b], 
   boundary3[c] <= b <= boundary4[c], funb3[c][b]];
Plot[Table[f[c][b], {c, .3, .8, .1}] // Evaluate, {b, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image]